How to position text that is left aligned in the middle - animated text
I have to have the text left aligned so that when it animates, the text stays 'anchored' and doesn't push to the left which is what happens if I use text-align: center;
So, while this works, this issue is that I can only get it to work if I set a fixed width on loader-container. It basically needs to be the same width as the text. You can see from this example that the text is not in the middle.
This will also vary as I plan to make the text dynamic so the width will not always be the same. I tried using flex box and some other ideas but could not get it right.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dynamic Text Animation</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #010101;
        }

        .loader-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            width: 800px;
            text-align: left;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .loader {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 50px;
            font-weight: 700;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            display: inline-block;
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }

        .glitch {
            opacity: 0.5;
            animation: glitch 0.1s infinite alternate;
        }

        @keyframes glitch {
            0% {
                transform: translateX(0);
            }

            50% {
                transform: translateX(-10px);
            }

            100% {
                transform: translateX(10px);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="loader-container">
        <div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var words = ['PRIVACY POLICY'];
        var letters = "dxyhtfgq",
            speed = 150,
            steps = 2,
            loader = document.querySelector('#loader');

        function getRandomWord() {
            var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
            return randomWord;
        }

        function getRandomLetter() {
            var randomLetter = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
            return randomLetter;
        }

        function randomWordLoop() {
            var word = getRandomWord();
            var textLength = word.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {
                (function(i, word) {
                    letterAppear(i, word);
                })(i, word);
            }

            function letterAppear(i, word) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    randomLetters(i, word);
                }, speed * i);
            }

            function randomLetters(i, word) {
                for (var j = 0; j <= steps; j++) {
                    charsAnim(i, word, j);
                }
            }

            function charsAnim(i, word, j) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (j < steps) {
                        randomChar(i);
                    } else {
                        goodChar(i, word);
                    }
                }, (speed / steps) * j - speed / steps);
            }

            function randomChar(i) {
                var letter = getRandomLetter();
                var oldText = loader.textContent.slice(0, i);
                loader.innerHTML = oldText + `<span class="glitch">${letter}</span>`;
            }

            function goodChar(i, word) {
                var oldText = loader.textContent.slice(0, i);
                loader.innerHTML = oldText + word[i];
            }
        }

        randomWordLoop();
    </script>
</body>

</html>




A trick could be to create another div hidden with the same text and font values to retrieve its width and set it to .loader-container.
exemple


var words = ['PRIVACY POLICY'];
let size = document.createElement('div');
size.style.height = 0;
size.style.width = 'max-content';
size.style.overflow = 'hidden';
size.style.fontSize="50px";
size.style.fontWeight=700;
size.textContent = words;
document.body.appendChild(size)
document.querySelector('.loader-container').style.width = size.offsetWidth;

var letters = "dxyhtfgq",
  speed = 150,
  steps = 2,
  loader = document.querySelector('#loader');

function getRandomWord() {
  var randomWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  return randomWord;
}

function getRandomLetter() {
  var randomLetter = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  return randomLetter;
}

function randomWordLoop() {
  var word = getRandomWord();
  var textLength = word.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {
    (function(i, word) {
      letterAppear(i, word);
    })(i, word);
  }

  function letterAppear(i, word) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      randomLetters(i, word);
    }, speed * i);
  }

  function randomLetters(i, word) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= steps; j++) {
      charsAnim(i, word, j);
    }
  }

  function charsAnim(i, word, j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (j < steps) {
        randomChar(i);
      } else {
        goodChar(i, word);
      }
    }, (speed / steps) * j - speed / steps);
  }

  function randomChar(i) {
    var letter = getRandomLetter();
    var oldText = loader.textContent.slice(0, i);
    loader.innerHTML = oldText + `<span class="glitch">${letter}</span>`;
  }

  function goodChar(i, word) {
    var oldText = loader.textContent.slice(0, i);
    loader.innerHTML = oldText + word[i];
  }
}

randomWordLoop();
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(0, #000c 50%, #000a 50%), 
  linear-gradient(90deg,#000c 50%, #000a  50%)
  ;
  color: white;
}

.loader {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.glitch {
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation: glitch 0.1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes glitch {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(10px);
  }
}
<div class="loader-container">
  <div class="loader" id="loader"></div>
</div>




Thank you @G-Cyrillus! I did notice though that at the end the whole thing shifts to the left

If you also set the fontweight , both will end up to be the same size and there will be no shift . I wrote -- A trick ...  with the same text and font values ;) snippet updated for those not paying attention :P

Haha, good point. I will have to play around with it some more because while it is a lot better, if you keep refreshing the page you will see it still jumps sometimes.
